# Mysql Parameterized NULL Value Queries

Tags: python, mysql, etl

Hi I am trying to use parameterized MySQL queries with Python. Sometimes The values I am passing in are `NoneType` or `NULL`. 
When working with `NULL` or `NoneType` values in mysql, why wont `%s` or `%d` work for the insert query below?

```
class DBWork(object):
    def __init__(self, attackerip=None, victimip=None, shunlen=15, shuncount=1, shunreason=None, shunepoch=None,
                 shunerrorbool=False, shunerror=None, paloaddedepoch=None, paloremovedepoch=None,
                 lastshunlen=15):
        self.Id = None
        self.attackerip = attackerip
        self.victimip = victimip
        self.shunlen = shunlen
        self.shuncount = shuncount
        self.shunreason = shunreason
        self.shunepoch = shunepoch
        self.shundatetime = 'need to build this'
        self.shunerrorbool = shunerrorbool
        self.shunerror = shunerror
        self.paloaddedepoch = paloaddedepoch
        self.paloremovedepoch = paloremovedepoch
        self.lastshunlen = lastshunlen
        self.shunlen = shunlen
        self.newshunlen = lastshunlen * shuncount
```

...

```
    def HistoryInsert(self):
        insert_query = (
            "INSERT INTO `autoshun`.`shunhistory` "
            "(Id, attackerip, victimip, shunlen, shuncount, shunreason, shunepoch, shundatetime, shunerrorbool, "
            "shunerror, paloaddedepoch, paloremovedepoch) "
            "VALUES "
            "(NULL, %s, %s, %d, %d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s );"
        )
        values = [None, self.attackerip, self.victimip, self.shunlen, self.shuncount, self.shunreason, self.shunepoch,
                  self.shundatetime, self.shunerrorbool, self.shunerror, self.paloaddedepoch, self.paloremovedepoch]
        return self.cur.execute(insert_query, values)


sample = DBWork(attackerip='1.1.1.15', victimip='2.2.2.2', shunreason='hax', shuncount=1, )
#
sample.DBConnect()
sample.HistoryInsert()
```

(debug of `values` list)

```
<type 'list'>: [None, '1.1.1.15', '2.2.2.2', 15, 1, 'hax', None, 'need to build this', False, None, None, None] 


/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/dobbs/PycharmProjects/autoshun/sqlobjects.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dobbs/PycharmProjects/autoshun/sqlobjects.py", line 100, in <module>
    sample.HistoryInsert()
  File "/home/dobbs/PycharmProjects/autoshun/sqlobjects.py", line 93, in HistoryInsert
    return self.cur.execute(insert_query, values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: I haven't looked into your actual issue, but I did just notice that your values array begins with a `None` which I'd expect to be passed as the first variable, which would go into `attackerip`, then the next value, `self.attackerip` would be inserted into `victimip` and so on.

Comment: @AC yes the value array starts with `None` because that mysql Column is set to `Id, BIGINT(10), NOT NULL, AUTO INCREMENT`. passing a `NULL` value here autoincrements the row `Id`